# Animating the addition of a box to a list of boxes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-spring, framer-motion

I have a horizontal row of boxes, right aligned. I want to add a new box to the right side by having it gradually slide in, moving the other boxes to the left as it does so.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-curran-xqcbh?file=/src/App.js is where I've gotten. Here's my code:

```
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [texts, setTexts] = useState(["foo", "foo"]);

  return (
    <div className="m-2">
      <button
        className="btn btn-primary mb-3"
        onClick={() => {
          setTexts([...texts, "bar"]);
        }}
      >
        Add box
      </button>

      <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
        <AnimatePresence initial={false}>
          {texts.map((text, i) => (
            <motion.div
              key={i}
              positionTransition
              initial={{ x: 100 }}
              animate={{ x: 0 }}
              transition={{ duration: 2, type: "tween" }}
            >
              <div className="alert alert-primary mr-2" style={{ width: 100 }}>
                {text}
              </div>
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

There's two problems:

1. All the existing boxes move much faster to the left than the next box.
2. The existing boxes have a spring-like oscillation after they move. Instead I would like them to smoothly move to their destination, not overshoot it and oscillate.

Any ideas for where to go from here?

I used framer-motion but I'm not wedded to it, if another library makes this easier.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need a matching spring for the positionTransition.

```
  const spring = {
      duration: 2,
      type: "tween"
  };
  ...
  positionTransition={spring}
```

See example https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-mendel-zl1fl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize positionTransition could take settings besides a boolean :)